# Testing API rate limiting with Postman and Jetpacks

Tags: api, testing, postman

I am trying to set up a test suite using Postman and Jetpacks, for an API I am running. I'm kind of stuck testing the rate limiting. A part of it is pretty easy, inspecting the X-RateLimit headers. But I would like to run tests on the response given, when the limit is actually exceeded.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing tests you can use Javascript to differentiate different tests you want to run.

```
if ( responseCode.code === 204 ) {
    tests[ "204 response test" ] = responseCode.code === 204;
} else if ( responseCode.code !== 204 ) {
    tests[ "not 204 response test" ] = responseBody.has( "limit exceeded" );
} else {
```

}

So you can set up a test to run, if it shares the correct response run the first test (response code = 200). Else if the response is not 204 run the second test (the response body has "limit exceeded").

So effective POSTMAN will run a test based on the response received and decide if the intended behaviour was executed.

If you do a test run will multiple iterations (stress testing) POSTMAN would use a setup like this to run your first condition until it fails, then move onto reporting your next next condition where you ask it to search for your "limit exceeded" string.

Hope this helps.